# DownloadManager can not diwnload files with size more than 2 gb

Tags: android

I need to download file larger than 2gb via DownloadManager service. Looks like it uses Integer type in order to handle file size and does not show download progress. Can anybody help with this issue.
Please assist.
Thank you.

Comment: Write your own, or find an unencumbered open-source one with a license that fits your software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your custom DownloadManager service, as alternative